# Power BI - Relation between single date and date period

Tags: date, relationship, powerbi-desktop

I have one table with timebookings,
[image: timebookings]

another table with hourly rates for time periods.
[image: hourly rates]

What I try is to calculate the costs per timebooking. I want to get a new column in my timebooking table like this:
[image: calculated costs]

I am not able to get a relationship between these tables.

Can anybody please help me with this problem?

Best regards
Thomas

I think I have to use time or date intelligence in any way, but I cannot figure out, how to do that with my time periods.

Answer (score 0):

Create a **Calculated Column** as below-

```
costs = 

var current_company = timebookings[company]
var current_date = timebookings[date]
var current_hour = timebookings[hours]

var cost = 
CALCULATE(
    sum(periods[hourly_rate]),
    filter(
        ALL(periods),
        periods[company] = current_company
            && periods[from] <= current_date
            && periods[to] >= current_date
    )
)

return current_hour * cost
```

Here is the output-

[image]